# Trino API to get query history

Tags: presto, trino, presto-jdbc

Is there any way to get all the query history that is executed in trino?

I need an API or query to get the history of the executed query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/system.html#runtime-queries

```
show columns from system.runtime.queries;
select * from system.runtime.queries;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
https://<Trino_IP>/ui/api/query
```